# array_filter with a callback function

Tags: php, arrays, anonymous-function, array-filter

```
$thisQuestion = array_filter($pollQuestions,function($q) use ($questDataArr){
                      return $questDataArr[0] == $q["id"];
                    });
```

As I am using 2 variables here I was using this inline function . How can i create a callback function and pass extra parameter ?

Comment: You pass extra parameters with use(), like you have done. It would help if you showed us what those data types looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

- you don't want to use an anonymous function
- you need a function that keeps some state with it

The solution is to create a class:

```
class MyCallback {
    private $questDataArr;
    public function __construct($questDataArr) {
        $this->questDataArr = $questDataArr;
    }
    function callback($q) {
        return $this->questDataArr[0] == $q["id"];
    }
}

array_filter($pollQuestions, array(new MyCallback($questDataArr), 'callback'));
```